# "A lot of", "Many", or "Much" ingredients?

Tags: word-choice

Why is "many" correct in this sentence:

> You can add tomatoes and cheese and (a lot of/many/much) other ingredients on top.

Comment: *ingredient* is a countable noun

Comment: I don't see a problem with saying "lots of other ingredients", although it seems very informal.

Comment: _Many other ingredients_ means _a wide variety of different kinds_. (Are we talking pizza here?) _A lot of_ could be understood as meaning _a large quantity_.

Answer (score 4):

We can use 'a lot of' with countable or uncountable nouns - "*a lot of cars have passed over the bridge today*", "*a lot of bread has been baked today*", but the phrase is informal, and 'many' is considered more formal. This may be why it was selected as the correct answer in a school exercise.

> We use lots, a lot and plenty in informal styles to talk about
> quantities, amounts and degree. Lots and a lot *[informal]* are similar in meaning to much and many *[formal]*. Plenty means ‘enough’ or ‘more than enough’. Lots is even more informal than a lot: …

[Lot (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lot)